# Is 勇敢なアイデア the best translation for "brave ideas"

Tags: translation

I am looking for the best translation for the concept of a "**brave ideas**"

Not necessarily used in a sentence. Simply the phrase "brave ideas".

Is 勇敢なアイデア correct?

Comment: In English, *brave ideas* is an example of **hypallage**.  In a *drunken brawl*, the brawl isn't actually drunk – a brawl is not a person and is incapable of consuming alcohol itself.  Rather, the people taking part in the brawl are the ones who are actually drunk.  Likewise, your "brave ideas" are abstract concepts not capable of bravery themselves.  This sort of rhetorical device sometimes translates literally, but other times it doesn't work, so you might want to think about that when you come up with your Japanese version.  Who is brave in your intended context? How so?

Comment: So interesting! Would the actual abstract concept of "brave idea" best translate literally? EDIT: But to answer your question, and to get more specific. "A brave idea comes from the heart" is what I am trying to communicate.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question should be rephrased, as both 'brave' and 'the heart' aren't the most precise terms to use.

You should distill these terms to their essential meanings before translating until you have a tacit understanding of the nuances between Japanese and English.

I would rephrase the sentence as:

> Bold ideas come from one's innermost character [the depths of one's being].
>   大胆なアイディアは（人の）心の奥底［内なる自己］から生まれる。